# Sass adds extra space after unicode character in "content" CSS attribute

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm providing internationalization to Bootstrap's file selection input.
It's done via editing Sass variable, so I tried following

[image]

But Sass added extra space after "ą" character and it now looks like this:

[image]

This is how compiled CSS looks like:

[image]

How do I get rid of this extra space?

Comment: Hi, Did you try to use another SASS Compiler?? I tried to use your code and compiled it with **Prepros Compiler** and it all worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `''` for `pl:` use a `""` (Double qoutation) instead and it should work properly. Also declare  `@charset "UTF-8";` at the very beggining(not even a comment should preceed it). Check [this](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1663#issuecomment-120299843) for more.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your compiler. Im using gulp-sass to compile it and it works fine, it actually doesn't convert the "ą".

However as a workaround you could add:

```
 @charset "UTF-8";
```

above your custom-file-input class inside the sass file. This will force your compiler to compile in UTF-8.

Comment: Adding charset doesn't work. I use Sass compilation from Laravel Mix. Temporarily I just added plain <style> element in <head> section, it's somehow ugly but I wasn't able to find any better solution

Answer (score 0):

You probably declare value of ::after as a variable (I'm css not sass).
Try to build this variable with baby steps:

```
  $after = 'Przegl';  
  $after.= '\105';  
  $after.= 'daj';
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem like this:

```
&::after {
    content: 'Sărbă''tori fericite!';
}
```